# How to add login page in existing WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

One website was already running in WordPress.

It's a static website.

Now I want to add a login page to this site.

WordPress admin panel login is different.

Now I m asking whoever has access to this site. without a login should not access this site.

I have tried with the ultimate member plugin.

create new login page also

Both cases navigation menu coming with this login page.

any suggestion to create a login page?

Comment: You are talking about header nav menu or admin bar at the top ?

Comment: header nav menu

Comment: Usualy nav menu is located in header.php . Wrap your nav with condition if(is_user_logged_in()){ show nav} Read more here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

Answer (score 0):

Use **FORCE LOGIN** plugin solve the issue.

Thank you all